# public ajax websites

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am creating a tutorial for jquery and was wondering if there are any public websites, to which i can make ajax requests, that will return json string for a simple list, string, objects etc. Are there any websites like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSFiddle has all the things that you might need.

see here: http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html

Comment: @Matt Ball, yes that is true, but the OP can use jsFiddle for examples

Answer (score 2):

You should set up your own server to do this, or (as [@Neal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5969815/public-ajax-websites/5969835#5969835) hints) use [jsFiddle's embed feature](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/embedding.html).

Why? Unless you use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP), the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) prevents ajax requests across domains. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy